# Accessing the first byte AFTER a Delphi record, class etc. from assembly routine

Tags: delphi, assembly, record

It’s well known for assembly coders in Delphi that any fields of a record, class etc. can be accessed from an `asm` code routine as shown in the example below:

```
type 

THeader = packed record
  field1: uint64;
  field2: uint32;
end;

(* some code here *)

asm
  mov rax, [rcx + THeader.field1]
  mov edx, [rcx + THeader.field2]
end;
```

But what if – as the name suggests – this is just a header of a big, unpredictable sized data stream and I want to access the actual start position of the data stream (that is, the first byte *after* the header)?
A simple solution might be the one shown below (but I prefer something less unnatural, without defining a constant):

```
type

  THeader = packed record
    field1: uint64;
    field2: uint32;
  end;
  (* start_of_data_stream: byte; *)

const 
  SIZEOFTHEADER = sizeof(THeader);

(* some code here *)

asm
  mov al, [rcx + SIZEOFTHEADER] (* [rcx + THeader.start_of_data_stream] *)
end;
```

Any better ideas, maybe?

Comment: Not sure this warranted the d/vote.

Comment: BTW, in C you can do this without inline asm, with a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) at the end of a struct.  But if you are going to use asm, prefer `movzx eax, byte [rcx + ...]` for loading a single byte on modern CPUs.  Merging into the low byte of an existing register (mov to AL) can be more expensive than a zero-extending load (movzx)

Comment: @PeterCordes Need Delphi and definitely asm for this particular purpose, so I have no choice here. Anyway, thanks for the zero extending load remark, at least this surely deserves an upvote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `TYPE(typename)` to find the size of the type in an asm expression. For example:

```
mov al, [rcx + TYPE(THeader)]
```

This (together with a number of other useful operators) is documented: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Assembly_Expressions#Expression_Operators

Comment: Note that I did not know that this operator existed until I read the documentation.

Comment: Right answer. Short, elegant. period.

Comment: Reading that page: "Numeric constants must be integers, and their values must be between 2,147,483,648 and 4,294,967,295."  Looks like they dropped a `-`.

Comment: @Brian indeed, and I bet that they also forgot to update it to account for 64 bit